# aui-scheduler - How to display events in week view as list

Tags: liferay-aui

I want to show a week view as list of events for each day, as shown in the picture below. Something like in the month view, but with one day per column.

Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add a [`SchedulerWeekView`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerWeekView.html) to the [`views`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerBase.html#attr_views) attribute of the [`Scheduler`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerBase.html) like so:

```
new Y.Scheduler({
    // your code here...
    views: [new Y.SchedulerWeekView()]
});
```

Here's a runnable example:

```js
YUI().use(
  'aui-scheduler',
  function(Y) {
    var events = [{
      content: 'Event1',
      endDate: new Date(2013, 1, 4, 17),
      startDate: new Date(2013, 1, 4, 15)
    }, {
      content: 'Event2',
      endDate: new Date(2013, 1, 4, 19),
      startDate: new Date(2013, 1, 4, 17)
    }, {
      content: 'Event3',
      endDate: new Date(2013, 1, 6, 16),
      startDate: new Date(2013, 1, 6, 14)
    }, {
      content: 'Event4',
      endDate: new Date(2013, 1, 6, 19),
      startDate: new Date(2013, 1, 6, 16)
    }];

    new Y.Scheduler({
      boundingBox: '#scheduler',
      date: new Date(2013, 1, 4),
      items: events,
      render: true,
      views: [new Y.SchedulerWeekView()]
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div id="scheduler"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But I want to show the day in column not positioned by time. All event boxes aligned to the top.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, because the event time can be changed by dragging and dropping the events. So it's position is important to the data.

Comment: Yea, so that answers my question - it is not possible. I don't want to be able drag&drop events. I want to have an overview of events per day. So Alloy Scheduller is not suitable for me. I used jQuery FullCalendar instead.